# JMeter boundary extraction from header

Tags: jmeter, boundary

Does anyone know how does boundary extractor work when using on request headers ? What ever I do I can not get the value.

Comment: Do you mean response headers? Show what you have tried and the values returned in header

Comment: I made a mistake, yes I meant response headers. It works fine now.